# Does Events Handlers in JavaScript for one event fired as FIFO, LIFO or in parallel?

Tags: javascript, events, internals

Does Events Handlers in JavaScript for one event fired as FIFO, LIFO or in parallel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very simple. DOM Level 2 Events module [does not specify order](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-basic-h3) in which event listeners are to be fired. However, DOM Level 3 Events module [does specify order](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) **to be the same as registration** one.

First registered — first fired.

Note that DOM Level 3 Events module is **still a draft**, whereas Level 2 one is a **recommendation**. Nevertheless, modern browsers often follow semantics of exactly this draft Level 3 specification, instead of an older Level 2 one.

In practice, IIRC, only **IE doesn't respect order** of event listeners. All other browsers implement it as FIFO (and as described in DOM L3 Events). You can also find [related tests online](http://www.phpied.com/order-of-execution-of-event-listeners/) :)

Comment: Indeed I seriously hate IE8 right now because it's executing my events in REVERSE order relative to every other browser on the planet *including* IE7.  Grr.

Answer (score 3):

Due the single threaded nature of JavaScript, events and timers are queued up and executed sequentially one at time,  they run when there's been an opening in the execution.

This is best demonstrated with a diagram:

[image: Events and Timers]

After the first block finishes its execution, there are two asynchronous events waiting, the *Mouse Click Callback* and the *Timer*, the browser picks the *Mouse Click* in this example, and the timer will wait until the next possible time, in order to execute.

Check this really good article about [Timers and Events](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) by John Resig.

Answer (score 0):

PPK has an excellent writeup on Event bubbling and Event Capturing.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html